# custom email headers - cakephp 1.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, email-headers

How do I go about setting custom email headers within cakephp 1.3?

I am trying the following:

$this->Email->headers = array('X-statusID' => $status_id);

But the header does not exist in the email when I read it using PHP IMAP.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I read in [the API documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/1.3/class-EmailComponent.html#_header), it should just be:

```
$this->Email->header(array('X-statusID' => $status_id));
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that but that header still didn't come though in the email.

Comment: Have you tried `$this->Email->__header[] = "X-statusID: $status_id";`?

Comment: Hmm... I just tried both methods I provided and both methods worked for me. However, I only checked the headers by using Gmail's "Show original" feature.

Comment: Ahh.. I just checked with a gmail email and it too shows up for me. Must be something wrong with the way I am reading the headers. Thanks for your help.